# Error "object no contiene definición al intentar acceder a propiedad de una clase

Tags: c#, vb.net, interop

Tengo la siguiente clase la cual guardará unos datos extraídos de MS project:

```
public class Milestone
    {
        MSProject.Project ActiveProject = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveProject;
        public int startDay;
        public string startFullMonthName;
        public int startYear;
        public int endDay;
        public string endFullMonthName;
        public int endYear;

        public Milestone(MSProject.Task oSubTask)
        {
            string pjStartDate = oSubTask.GetField(ActiveProject.Application.FieldNameToFieldConstant("Start", MSProject.PjFieldType.pjTask));
            DateTime startDate = dateToName(pjStartDate);
            string pjEndDate = oSubTask.GetField(ActiveProject.Application.FieldNameToFieldConstant("Start", MSProject.PjFieldType.pjTask));
            DateTime endDate = dateToName(pjEndDate);

            startDay = startDate.Day;
            startFullMonthName = startDate.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es"));
            startYear = startDate.Year;

            endDay = endDate.Day;
            endFullMonthName = endDate.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es"));
            endYear = endDate.Year;
        }

    }
```

Luego creo una lista de objectos de la clase `Milestone` anteriormente creada, y deseo leer las propiedades de este. Sin embargo cuando intento acceder a estas (en el foreach) me muestra el error "object no contiene definición para startDay".

```
    List<object> milestoneList = new List<object>();

    MSProject.Project ActiveProject = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveProject;
    MSProject.Task oSubTask;

    int pjStart = 101;

    for (int i = pjStart; i <= ActiveProject.Tasks.Count; i++)
    {
        oSubTask = ActiveProject.Tasks[i];
        if (oSubTask.Summary)
        {
            Milestone m = new Milestone(oSubTask);
            milestoneList.Add(m);
        }
    }

    int rows = milestoneList.Count();
    int columns = 6;
    object[,] data = new object[rows, columns];
    object[] marray = milestoneList.ToArray();

    foreach (var m in milestoneList)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(m.startDay); // aquí intento acceder a la propiedad
    }
```

Por otro lado cuando hago un debug, dentro la ventana de locales si los muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`milesstoneList` es una lista de del tipo `System.Object` y el tipo `System.Object` no tiene ninguna propiedad llamada `startDay`. Tienes que castear o convertir el tipo `System.Object` al tipo de datos que tiene la propiedad `startDay`, en este caso a `Milestone`, para poder acceder a la propiedad:

```
 foreach (var m in milestoneList)
 {
        var mileStone = (Milestone)m;// conviertes el tipo System.Object a Milestone
        Debug.WriteLine(mileStone.startDay);
 }
```

Tambien puedes utilizar el tipo `dynamic` donde se intentara acceder a la propiedad en runtime si existe:

```
foreach (dynamic m in milestoneList)
 {

        Debug.WriteLine(m.startDay);
 }
```